# Entity Framework - Database and model columns/types don't match - mapping options

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, database-design

I have a model class using C#/Entity Framework which was originally receiving data parsed from an Excel file, but which now I have to rewire to a database where all the matching columns are of type varchar, but the model is much more mixed with int, decimal, string, long members, etc.

And the model member types make sense, the all-varchar columns in the database don't, really. Also, the model class is referenced in numerous places and changing the member types now would no doubt break a lot of code and require a lot of rewriting.

So what's the best way to proceed and map varchar  columns to  basically any and every primitive type in C#/Entity Framework? Say my model class looks something like...

```
public class Data
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public long VisitKey { get; set; }
        public long CodeKey { get; set; }
        public short GroupKey { get; set; }
        public int GroupVersion { get; set; }
        public int Classification {get;set;}
}
```

...and the column names and such match in the SQL database, it's just that all columns are varchar. I think I can assume for now that I can't change the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data model that your application uses can stay the same. However, you will need to create new properties of type string and map them to your database, removing the applicable mappings of your original data model (ones that aren't a string). Then you will need to change your getters and setters of each property on your original data model to reference the new string fields.

It will be important to provide data conversion so that the integers get converted to strings and then strings to integers. This will all have to happen in the getters and setters in your original data model.

The end result is your application will use your original data model but behind the scenes this data is converted into a format that the database can work with.

It is recommended to change your original implementation to a partial class. Then, in a separate file to make things easier, add on to that implementation as such:

```
public partial class Data
    {
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; } // only property left that is mapped to
                                                  // database because the type matches
        public long VisitKey 
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(_visitKey);
            }
            set
            {
                _visitKey = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public long CodeKey
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(_codeKey);
            }
            set
            {
                _codeKey = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public short GroupKey
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt16(_groupKey);
            }
            set
            {
                _groupKey = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public int GroupVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(_groupVersion);
            }
            set
            {
                _groupVersion = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        public int Classification
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(_classification);
            }
            set
            {
                _classification = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        // these fields need to be mapped to the database
        private string _visitKey;
        private string _codeKey;
        private string _groupKey;
        private string _groupVersion;
        private string _classification;
    }
```

You didn't mention whether you were using Code First or Database First. This could change the way my suggestion above is implemented. My example above is suited for Code First because you have granular control of the mappings.

To easily switch to Code First, use EF Power Tools to reverse engineer Code First using your existing database, implement the suggestion above, and then change your database mappings.

Otherwise, if using Database First, SLC's answer is spot on and you will have some properties auto-generated from the database as strings.

I hope this helps and good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be to take advantage of the fact your EF model should be marked as a partial class, and build your own code for it.

So your EF model will basically be:

```
/* autogenerated */
public partial class MyDatabaseTable
{
   // Everything is a string because it's generated from your DB
   public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
   public string VisitKey { get; set; }
   public string CodeKey { get; set; }
}
```

Then make your own class:

```
public partial class MyDatabaseTable
{
   public int AccountNumberAsId { get { return int.parse(AccountNumber); } };
   ...
}
```

However it looks like you're doing it in reverse. If you can't alter your model you're screwed even if there is a solution. Maybe just build a new EF model? You could use an interface for all of your operations and alter the .tt so you can handle both types of model.

Answer (score 0):

I import from a text file into a staging table that contains `varchar(max)` columns for all fields then I check that the data in the staging table is valid - no duplicates, numbers really are numbers,  required fields are present, strings will fit without truncating etc. If everything is OK then I insert the data into the main table used by my application and delete the staged data.

If it's not OK I report the problems to the user.

So - two models. One for the import and another for the application. Keep the model you've got and add this one:

```
public class DataImport
{
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string VisitKey { get; set; }
        public string CodeKey { get; set; }
        public string GroupKey { get; set; }
        public string GroupVersion { get; set; }
        public string Classification {get;set;}
}
```

Then go write an import method:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Import(string filePath
                                                        , string formatFilePath)
{
   var errors = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

   ImportFromFileToStagingTable(filepath, formatfilepath);

   IQueryable<DataImport> staged = Uow.DataImportRepository.All;

   var invalidAccNo = staged.Where(p => String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.VisitKey))
                            .Select(p => new
                            {
                               Key = "Missing VisitKey",
                               Value = p.AccountNumber
                            });

   var invalidCodeKey = staged //etc

   var query = invalidAccNo.Concat(invalidCodeKey)

   errors.AddRange(query.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key
                                                                    , x.Value)));

   if (errors.Count == 0)
   {
      TransferToMainTable();
      DeleteImport();
      Uow.Save();
   }

   return errors;
}
```